# Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined - only in IE9

Tags: javascript

I only receive this error in Internet Explorer 9. IE7, IE8 and IE10 run the script fine. It is a banner of fading images, one after the other all stacked and fade in to each other.

When you attempt to load the page on IE9, it throws an error. The error occurs within prototype.js and I get this error.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference 
>   prototype.js, line 334 character 24

Why would this happen in IE9 but not any earlier version??

Comment: What code are you running to trigger this error? What's the code in prototype.js around line 334?

Comment: The code on line 334 is `   if (e != $break) throw e;
`

I'm not exactly sure what is running. Its a div with 4 stacked images, effected by 3 different js libraries to get it fading in and out. Site is www.nobellearning.com/hla

Comment: I opened your page in IE9 and I see 2 errors.  One is `$jquery('#wpcontent_slider').coinslider({})`.  Your object has keys and not values.  Your 2nd error is on line 1400 character 13 for me. `if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.opera){element.style.filter = element.getStyle('filter').replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,'');}`  This is inside of a `setStyle` method.  Where are you calling `setStyle`?  This seems to be for when an `'opacity'` is set.

Comment: Also, try upgrading to the latest version of prototype.js

Comment: It must be calling setStyle within one of the libraries. I haven't called that my self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the issue after a few hours of hair pulling and teeth grinding.

I did not realize that scriptaculous was reliant upon prototype.

I was updating prototype while leaving an outdated version of scriptaculous  effects linked which was throwing many errors.

After updating to scriptaculous 1.9 and then updating prototype to 1.7, all was well and no errors are thrown.

Thank you all to those who helped, I appreciate all the comments!

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message, because I was using a .html() operation on an XML tag.

```
var myXML = '<someTag att1=""><cell></cell></someTag>' ;

$(myXML).html(); // which was giving the error msg.

// Instead use the below option 

$(myXML).children() ;// instead this work with IE
```

Note: Above example is not what I actually tried, it's just to give a representation of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the X-UA-Compatible tag. Many libraries do not work well with IE9 and need to be run in IE8 compatible mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: where should I put that? at the top of my page, or inside one of the js files?

Comment: This should go in the `<head></head>` of your page.

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</head>

Comment: I'd argue that most libraries don't work well in IE8!  Also I'd argue that you should always use `IE=edge`.  Plus setting it to run in IE8 mode might break other things, like CSS.

Comment: ok, I should possibly rephrase it as many of the not so recent libraries do not work very well with IE9. Not because IE9 has an issue, rather they were written to work around certain things in the previous versions of IE.

Comment: Then maybe it's time to upgrade libraries?

Comment: Apparently the version of prototype that came with the fader is 1.5. I tried to upgrade to the newest version of prototype (1.7) and even one older (1.6.1) to no avail. Still throws errors, and I'm not sure where to start debugging prototype. I have added the X-UA-Compatible to the header in hopes that ie9 will render it as ie8

Comment: @v2b I'm not 100%. I have IE10, so I can switch between ie10, ie9, ie8, and ie7. It works when I set it to view in IE8. If I switch it to ie9 it forces a view of ie9 regardless of the x-ua ie=8. I wont know until I test it on an IE9 only browser I think

Comment: Is it possible it is not working in IE9, because the way the script works is by lowering the top image opacity, while simultaneously raising the image below it's opacity. As most of us know Opacity does not work in IE9, it needs to be declared using a filter.

I'm thinking this is the main reason it is throwing an error in IE9, and falling back to a standard image rotater in IE8.

Comment: Changing versions of Prototype throws the error 'Stack size exceeded'

Answer (score 1):

Well, most of the time this error occures because of the .html() operation in jquery to parse XML. Remove this and use .text() instead will solve the problem.

Comment: wonder why this was not marked as the answer! this was my solution!